# Atualização de variváveis OnInit - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-6

Tenho a variável:

```
compromissoInicio = ‘’;
```

No `onInit`, tenho:

```
this.enviaForm(this.funcoes.homeAtualiza);
```

Ou seja, se `homeAtualiza` for `true`, o sistema atualiza as informações, conforme abaixo:

```
... submita form ...
this.compromissoInicio = retorno[‘compromisso_inicio’];
```

No HTML, tenho:

```
{{ compromissoInicio | date:‘dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss’ }}
```

O problema é que, caso `homeAtualiza` seja `true`, toda vez que voltar à página home, o sistema irá consultar o webservice, desnecessariamente.

E, se `homeAtualiza` for `false`, o conteúdo de `{{ compromissoInicio | date:‘dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss’ }}` fica vazio.

Preciso de uma forma em que `compromissoInicio` permaneça sempre com o último conteúdo carregado, caso a página não seja atualizada, no `onInit`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode deixar essa variável no service e alimentar ela assim que recebe o valor do webservice. e quando for false, você analisa se essa variável esta com valor caso ela esteja nula ai sim você consome o web service de novo.